# i want to send one div innerHtml to another page div for add to cart purpose

Tags: javascript, html

```
let card1 = ()=>{
    var a = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
    
    var newDiv=document.getElementById("newDiv")
    newDiv.innerHTML=a
}

card1();

let card2=()=>{
    var firstpageDiv = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
   
    var secondpageDiv = document.getElementById("div2")
        secondpageDiv.innerHTML = firstpageDiv
}

card2();
```

Comment: are you using a server-side programming language? Also, you can use local storage, or cache.

Comment: And your question/problem is...?